# Downloading certain columns of a Bigquery table using CLI by redirecting stdout to a file

Tags: google-bigquery

[This](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data) official document and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493533/how-to-download-all-data-in-a-google-bigquery-dataset) stackoverflow answer here talks about exporting a table to cloud storage and then downloading it. An answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49738175/bigquery-export-csv-certain-columns) stackoverflow question confirms that exporting few columns is not possible.

However, I think there is another simple way do this. Make a query (`bq`) using CLI and redirect the output to a text file. I tried and it worked.

- However, I got only 100 rows as output.
- So, next I used the flag --max_rows and set the maximum number of rows as desired.
- Did the size estimation of the output with `--dry_run` flag and the output was well within all the limits.
- This time also the query returned `Done` but nothing was outputed (redirecting stdout) in the file.

Not sure why? Any help will be appreciated.
If you want I can share the queries too. Please let me know if anymore information is needed.

Comment: have you checked this? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#downloading_and_saving_query_results_from_a_ui

Comment: @AlbertAlbesa Thanks. I read the document. The section you are pointing to talks about getting from UI and that too it states that only limited number of row can be pulled.
I am looking for a CLI solution which can help be to download the entire table.

Comment: How many rows has your output? Also, if you would like a CLI solution you can always have a python script save the result as a dataframe (like pandas) and then save as csv. have you checked this? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-storage-python-pandas#install_the_client_libraries

Comment: My output has 2853930000 rows with each row having 7 Integer. I am querying a public dataset, now with this large data I get responseTooLarge error as well.

Thanks for pointing to the document; I will check that.

Comment: If it is a public dataset, it would be great if you shared which dataset and query are you trying to perform for reproduction! :)